# Can C# (somehow) work out the type constraints itself when a generic type is passed as a generic type reference?

Tags: c#, generics

Given the following classes:

```
public class ClassA<T1, T2, T3>
{
}

public class ClassB<T0, T1, T2, T3>
    where T0 : ClassA<T1, T2, T3>
{
}
```

Is there a way in C# to be able to declare **ClassB** without the duplication of all the types present on **ClassA**; that C# can work these out itself from the type passed in? For example:

```
public class ClassB<T0>
    where T0 : ClassA<T1, T2, T3>
{
}
```

Thanks in advance for your responses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No this is not possible. Generic class level type parameters need to be defined if you wish to use them anywhere inside the class. You are trying to define T0 in terms of ClassA with type parameters that are not part of the ClassB definition so obviously it won't compile.

You could do something like:

```
ClassB<T0> where T0: ClassA<Int, Int, String> { }
```

This would limit `ClassB` to only accepting instance of `ClassA` or `ClassA` subtypes where the type parameters were `Int, Int, String`.

Alternatively you could do something like:

```
ClassB<T0, T1, T2, T3> where T0: ClassA<T1, T2, T3> { }
```

This would allow you to leave ClassB's reference to ClassA generic (rather than limiting the type parameters of ClassA in it's usage in ClassB. But, it smells a bit fishy to me.

Comment: Isn't the last thing you suggest exactly what the OP has in his original that he wants to get rid of?

Comment: Yes, it is. The answer says NO what he's suggesting IS NOT possible. Here are the possible solutions.

Comment: Thanks @ThomasCook. I suspected that this was the case.